# Text properties in interactive mode

Tags: emacs, elisp

How can i get the text properties values in interactive mode (for character in (point) for (current-buffer)? run functions like, `get-text-property, get-char-property, get-pos-property` .... etc in M-x mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to see what text properties there is at a specific point, place the cursor there and issue <kbd>C-u C-x =</kbd>.

Otherwise, you can run arbitrary elisp interactively by <kbd>M-: (get-text-property (point) 'face) RET</kbd>.

Comment: curious to know, why M-: instead of M-x meant for func invocation?

Comment: You use `M-x` to invoke an interactive function by name. `M-:`, on the other hand, allows you to evaluate an arbitrary elisp expression.